# Writing Gnome 2 panel applets in Java

Tags: java, gnome

Is there a way to write gnome-panel gui applet (like hamster, for example) using JVM application?

If it is not possible to do it using java, what other languages are available?

(I'm using Gnome 2 on Ubuntu)

Comment: Java is not well suited to getting into the guts of the OS, if that is what you mean.  What exactly does the proposed app. do?

Comment: @AndrewThompson - just for my projects. Currently, I want a simple stopwatch. And I do not need to get into guts of the OS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Java bindings for GTK+ exists (see http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php and http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net), I don't think it is enough for creating panel applets. I would expect you to have better success with **C#/Mono** (using Gtk#), **Python**, or **C**.

C: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove/PanelAppletTutorial
Python: http://www.pygtk.org/articles/applets_arturogf/